# !function(){ }() vs (function(){ })()

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, iife

While reviewing some of the code written in the Twitter Bootstrap Javascript, it looks like they're calling immediately invoked anonymous functions like this:

```
!function( $ ) {

     ...

}(window.jQuery || window.ender);
```

Where I've traditionally seen this same thing accomplished this way:

```
(function($) {

    ...

})(window.jQuery || window.ender);
```

The first way seems a bit hacky, and I'm not sure if there is any benefit or reason for doing it this way rather than the second way?  **Note that I understand how it works, I'm looking to understand  why they chose that way to do it.**

Comment: Here's [a blog post](http://www.wordsbyf.at/2011/10/31/i-dont-write-javascript/) by [the person that wrote it](http://www.twitter.com/fat).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between (function(){})(); and function(){}();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423228/), [Does parenthetical notation for self-invoked functions serve a purpose in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750231/)

Comment: @outis: I don't believe that's a duplicate; this is asking why `!function(){}()` rather than `(function(){})()`, not `(function(){})()` vs `function(){}()`. (In some cases, the last will cause a syntax error. Neither of the first two will.)

Comment: thanks @icktoofay, now that i've read that and looked closer at how it is written... most of it annoys the shit out of me ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- One less character when minified.
- The `!` should handle where other JavaScript code is concatenated before this and doesn't have a trailing semi-colon.

There is not a huge difference. I would use whatever you were more comfortable with. You should probably toss something at the start of your example to avoid...

#### base.js

```
var lol = function() {
   alert(arguments[0]);
}
```

#### im-concat-to-base.js

```
(function() {
    // Irrelevant.
})();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb7gr/).

Toss in a leading `;` and she works...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmvtN/).

...or a `!` like the Twitter Bootstrap...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCU4G/).

Answer (score 14):

They're both ways of getting past the ambiguity in the grammar. Neither is more "hacky" than the other. It's just a style choice.

You could also do this:

```
0 + function( $ ) {
  // ...
} ( window.jQuery || window.ender );
```

Or:

```
parseInt(function( $ ) {
  // ...
} ( window.jQuery || window.ender ) );
```

Comment: I would be very confused if someone used `parseInt()` like that :P

Comment: Yes me too!  The point is that the two in the original question represent choices of something *less* weird among the many possibilities :-)

Comment: @Pointy Neither is more "hacky" than the other => do you mean that both are hacks, not regular js notations?

Comment: They're all "regular" JavaScript idioms. The point is that the instantiation of a function is just a thing you can do in the middle of *any* JavaScript expression.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the evaluation step of `!undefined` you could also use the `void` operator to remove the ambiguity:

```
void function($) {
     ...
}(window.jQuery || window.ender);
```

Has a kind of C quality to it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One answer that I've yet not seen is that it avoids surrounding your entire function with parentheses. Outside of aesthetic considerations, this can be a plus for some editors which use parentheses to determine the level of indentation of a line.