# What's the difference between function(){}() and !function(){}()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [!function(){ }() vs (function(){ })()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305915/function-vs-function)

So I was just reading through the source of the new Bootstrap (2.0) from Twitter and noticed that there is an exclamation mark before the self-invoking anonymous function. When I saw this I immediately thought "Oh crap, there's a new, better way to do this?".

See for yourself!

- http://markdotto.com/bs2/js/bootstrap-modal.js
- http://markdotto.com/bs2/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js
- http://markdotto.com/bs2/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js
- http://markdotto.com/bs2/js/bootstrap-popover.js
- http://markdotto.com/bs2/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js
- http://markdotto.com/bs2/js/bootstrap-tab.js

Anyways, what's the difference? There must be a reason for it because they use it consistently in all of their JavaScript plugins (for Bootstrap).

Another thing I noticed was the "use strict" right after this. I don't think it's related to my previous inquiry, but can anyone explain this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function(){} ();
```

*By itself* (see Point's comment) isn't going to be valid, since

```
function() {}
```

is a function declaration.  To invoke it immediately, you need to get the JavaScript engine to treat the function as an *expression*.  People usually do this as either of

```
(function(){}) ();  //more common

(function(){} ()); // Papa Crockford's preference:
```

with

```
!function(){}();
```

simply being a shorthand version of the same thing.

Comment: +1 Though later isn't required but a good practice accoding to Doughlas Crackford :)

Comment: @gdoron - and I'm capped now.  Better get back to work :)

Comment: The first one is not valid if that's all there is, but if (for example) there's something like `x = ` before it then it's OK.

Comment: Thanks! I also found this [article](http://www.wordsbyf.at/2011/10/31/i-dont-write-javascript/) written by the dude who wrote the Javascript for Bootstrap.

Comment: @Johnny - that's a great article, I'll have to save it.  Though I don't think I'm a good enough developer to get away with leaving off semi-colons like that.  You have to know the langauge inside out to know when that'll work, and when it'll bite you

Comment: Something else worth noting is `!function(){}()` throws a "suspicious code" warning in Google's closure compiler while `;(function(){})()` and `(function(){}())` do not. Interesting.

Answer (score 8):

If you have 2 scripts:

`script1.js`:

```
(function(){

})()
```

`script2.js`:

```
(function(){

})()
```

And you concatenate them, you get:

```
(function(){

})()
(function(){

})()
```

This causes an error, while:

```
!function(){

}()
!function(){

}()
```

Doesn't.

Comment: This is also the reason some scripts use a semicolon at the start: `;(function(){}())`

Comment: So, would it by safe to say `;(function(){}())` and `!function(){}()` serve the same purpose?

Comment: The semicolon just ends the line. If you don't omit it, then it won't cause a problem. It does not serve the same purpose as `!function(){}();`

Answer (score 3):

The [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), section 12.4, says:

> An *ExpressionStatement* cannot start
>   with the `function` keyword because that
>   might make it ambiguous with a
>   *FunctionDeclaration*.

So if you want an expression statement that executes an anonymous function, you have to work around this restriction. Adding a `!` (which just negates the result of the function) makes it clear to the interpreter that it's not a function declaration, avoiding this ambiguity.