# Not self invoking anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap css uses the following:

```
!function( $ ) {
}( window.jQuery )
```

That's different than the self-invoking anonymous function call that I originally learned:

```
(function($) {
})(jQuery);
```

Q: Is that just preference you think? I mean the not symbol instead of enclosing it in parenthesis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [!function(){ }() vs (function(){ })()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305915/function-vs-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Q: Is that just preference you think?"*

Yes, but using a unary `!` operator, you can avoid a few bugs when you forget a semicolon before the IIFE, which can cause the `()` to be interpreted as a function call.

```
alert('foo')  // alerts 'foo'

(function() {  // TypeError: undefined is not a function
    alert('bar');
})()
```

Here the outer `()` is interpreted as a function call. It's trying to call whatever was returned from the `alert()` function, which of course returns `undefined`, which isn't a function.

---

```
alert('foo')  // alerts 'foo'

!function() {
    alert('bar');  // alerts 'bar'
}()
```

No troubles with this one, since the `!` is a unary operator that only evaluates the operand  to its right.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you very much "am not i am".

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn Also note, that Bootstrap ([on purpose!](http://www.wordsbyf.at/2011/10/31/i-dont-write-javascript/)) uses no semicolons, which makes the `!` syntax necessary. Or vice-versa: Using the `!` operator allows them to skip semicolons.

Comment: The second example isn't a type error at all, unless you omit the opening (and corresponding closing) parentheseis. `(function(){}())` is identical to `(function(){})();`. The use of the `!` operator simply means the grouping parenthesis can be omitted, so it saves a single character.

Comment: @RobG: The second example? I didn't say that one was a type error. Only the first one.

Comment: The one that says `(function() { // TypeError...` is not a type error. Writing: `function(){...}()` is a syntax error though.

Comment: You are being misled, jsfiddle has bugs—in IE I get `TypeError: Object expected`. In a function expression using the grouping operator, the "call operator" can be inside or outside the group, it doesn't matter, as long as it's adjacent.

Comment: @RobG: I made no claim as to the proper position of the call operator on the anonymous function. What I said was that the *outer* set of `()` is being *interpreted* as a call operator, and is attempting to invoke the return value of the `alert()` call. The `alert()` returns `undefined`, which is why you get a `TypeError`. We can get rid of the *trailing* `()`, and get the same error.

Comment: ...[here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/BGyaq/) to mess with. It replaces `alert()` with `test()`, which takes the string, alerts it, then returns a function that anticipates receiving a function, and invokes it. Because the outer `()` around the function is interpreted as a function call, the returned function is invoked, and the function in the `()` is passed, and invoked by the function we returned. I made the passed function also return a function so the final `()` could invoked it. Just add a `;` after `test()`, and the returned functions are no longer invoked.

Comment: Your post says that `(function(){alert('bar');})()` produces a type error. It doesn't, it's valid javascript and alerts "bar". The "outer ()" is a grouping operator that tells the parser that `function` is the start of a function expression. The trailing "()" is also a grouping operator, since it follows a function expression it's seen as containing a parameter list (albeit an empty one) and causes the function to be called.

Comment: @RobG: It produces a `TypeError` because it follows the `alert('foo')`, which doesn't terminate with a semicolon, so the code is interpreted as `alert('foo')(function(){...})()`. [Here's the example](http://jsbin.com/oxucaf/2/edit) in jsBin. Same result. I know you're probably going to claim that it has bugs. I also tested locally in Chrome and Firefox. Same result.

Comment: ...if you were right, then [the alternate example](http://jsfiddle.net/BGyaq/) I posted earlier would ignore the returned functions, and just alert `"foo"` and `"bar"`. This is obviously not the case. Insert the `;`, and you get the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Cool, totally missed the bit about the semi-colon, must be old age catching up on me. If that's the purpose, I don't think it's a good idea. Better to fix the error than ignore it.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, if you normally use the grouping operator for the IIFE, then it would make sense to insert the semicolon as a fix. Using `!` as the regular replacement can be help avoid the bugs, but ultimately you're right; bugs should be found and fixed. I personally don't use semicolons for my NodeJS code, and I use `void` for my IIFE.

Comment: Are you saying use use `void function(){}()` ?

Answer (score 1):

A statement starting with the `function` keyword is treated as a function declaration and must be followed by a name that is a valid identifier.

An anonymous function expression starts with the word `function`, but since there is no name, it can't be used where it might be confused with a function declaration. In most cases, the grouping operator is used to indicate a function expression:

```
(function() {
  /...
}());
```

or

```
(function() {
  /...
})();
```

You can also do:

```
var foo = function() {
}();
```

In all of the above, the `function` keyword isn't at the start of the statement so it's treated as the start of a function epxression. A name isn't required and the function can be immediately called.

It's the same with `!function...`. The parser sees the `!` and says "what follows is an expression". When it gets to `function` it knows it's the start of a function expression.

Using `!function…` instead of `(function…)` saves a single character, and possibly creates a bit of confusion as it's a less common way to write a function expression.