# what does ! mean before function() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [!function(){ }() vs (function(){ })()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305915/function-vs-function)

It is fairly standard common practice to write Js code like this:

```
function ($) {
    ...
}(jQuery)
```

I saw somebody using an exclamation mark first: `! function($)...`

What does it actually mean, and what is that good for?

Example from [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js) (code retrieved 2012-03-07):

```
!function ($) {

  $(function(){
    ...
})

}(window.jQuery)
```

Comment: ! is logical not operator it makes it a statement with the desired affect of having the anon func immediately executed.